# How to display USA content on my AppleTV while I'm in Mexico using hotel wifi?

Tags: wifi, appletv

How can I display USA content on my Apple TV while I'm in Mexico using a hotel's wifi?

(I've been told that AppleTV may only show Mexican content while I'm in Mexico.)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Unlocator](http://www.unlocator.com). It is a service to make it look like you are somewhere other than where you are. They have a seven-day trial so you can see if it does what you need. I'm not affiliated with the company, just a satisfied customer.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to use (manually configure in networking) a DNS server(s) that are hosted in the US. One possibility is to make note of your ISP's DNS server IP addresses when you're at home and then manually configure those when abroad.